# Cant write special characters like "á" "é" mysql server in a docker container

Tags: mysql, sql, docker

Cant write special characters like 'á' 'ñ' mysql server in a docker container

These are the character sets

```
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

When I try to copy and paste "Amélie" in the terminal, the actual output is "Amlie"

Comment: Try to set client, connection, and results all to utf8mb4

Answer (score 1):

Set the default characterset for the table or even for a column

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  col1 varCHAR(10) ,
  col2 varCHAR(10) 
 ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO t1
(`col1`, `col2`)
VALUES
('Amélie','Amélie');
```

Resuls in

```
Select * From t1;

col1    col2
Amélie  Amélie
```

Comment: Result =
mysql> Select * From t1;
+-------+-------+
| col1  | col2  |
+-------+-------+
| Amlie | Amlie |
+-------+-------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Comment: look here please https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6aeac23376829d7ee73ac3bee2e5284e  what character set has your database maybe it helps ALTER DATABASE DBNAME CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;  make a backup before you change anything

Comment: The problem isn't with tabke charset, but with docker itself. did you found the solution?

Comment: the it is the collation you aren using. Please add to your question the create tabel as mentioned , so that we can see what you got but utf8o should always work. and there